# Algebraic topology book recommendations

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I'm a grad student and I just started seeing a a few algebraic topology things but I'm getting a bit lost so I'd like to do some extra digging.

Anyone know a good book to study the basics on homology? (my class is using Rotman's An intro to Algebraic Topology and Bredon's Topology and Geometry).

We also just started up with tensors and categories on a different class but we only have the professor's notes, is there a book where I can check out the basics on this too?

Comment: Maybe, you can review the book Munker's topology.

Comment: Hatcher & Bredon

Comment: I second Zest's recommendation on Hatcher for algebraic topology. For category theory, I recommend Emily Riehl's Category Theory in Context. Both are free on the internet.

Comment: I found Hatcher to be a more useful $second$ book. My first read was Rotman's Intro to Algebraic Topology.

Comment: I have read some chapters of Tammo Tom Dieck's "Algebraic Topology" and they are excellent.

Comment: I'm a little late to the party, but I wanted to add that you'll probably have to brush up on/learn some homological/commutative algebra. While Atiyah-MacDonald is the standard commutative algebra textbook, I'd recommend watching Harpreet Bedi's videos on YouTube for extra help. His videos really saved me when I took commutative algebra and came in handy when I first encountered spectral sequences.

Comment: i actually like the first chapter of rotman's "homological algebra". This will cover homology. The later chapters will cover tensor products. That might be an ok place to start

Answer (score 0):

- *An Introduction to Algebric Topology*, 1957, by [Andrew H. Wallace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_H._Wallace).

As the teaching of this discipline is very axiomatic, the author, a mathematician of international reputation, wanted to expose the main notions of algebraic topology *in a natural way* and to show the rationale for the geometrical constructions that are made. As far as I'm concerned, this goal of the author has been achieved thanks to this book.

- *Introduction aux catégories et aux problèmes universels*, 1971, by Jaffard and [Poitou](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_Poitou).

It's in French but I think it's a really good introductory text.

- For tensors, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. The canonical first-year grad-student book on algebraic topology is Hatcher. It's an extremely well-written, geometrically motivated, self-contained treatment of the subject that stays almost exclusively in the CW-complex category throughout. The caveats are that (1) some students need a bit more background in homological algebra to get through it (and even then, the treatment of Ext and Tor is a bit lacking); (2) there's a substantial jump in difficulty in some of extra materials at the ends of chapters (which are intended to be supplemental bonus topics anyway); (3) it may be hard sometimes to see the big picture in a way that covering, say, sheaf cohomology might help.
2. The best-written math book of any variety I'm familiar with Bott and Tu's "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology." I don't think it fits in the bill for a first algebraic topology course; it doesn't have a comprehensive enough range of topics, and they range between broad, introductory topics (e.g., de Rham cohomology on smooth manifolds) and ones that are probably too specialized for this level (e.g., rational homotopy theory). The first chapter (of four total; it's almost 90 pages long) on de Rham cohomology is exceptionally good, though, and it introduces the subject clearly with geometric motivation and covers both the theoretical basis of the subject and how to actually compute it. You'll definitely need to cover versions of cohomology for the topological or CW category, but this is a perfect self-contained introduction to the subject. (You mentioned homology rather than cohomology. If you're not familiar with them, these are closely related topics that are generally covered together.)
3. Fulton's "Algebraic Topology: A First Course" might be a bit elementary for what you have in mind, but it would make a great introduction to the subject if you're looking for motivation and geometrical intuition. Its conceit is that it's focused on the plane, covering topics like vector fields, the winding number, and getting to results like Cauchy's integral theorem via algebraic topology. It does go into arbitrary $\mathbb{R}^n$ later in the book, covering results like Stokes' theorem. I don't think it's a substitute for something more comprehensive and advanced like Hatcher, but you might like it for the basic, nuts and bolts of homology.
4. I personally don't like them, but you might consider Spanier's "Algebraic Topology" and Munkres' "Elements of Algebraic Topology." I think the former is too dry, unmotivated, and technical for this level, and I find Munkres' treatment (which is far more interested in simplicial complexes than, say, Hatcher) to be a slow and tedious slog that drains any enjoyment of what I find to be a fun and compelling subject. But these are commonly read books in the subject, and your experience may differ from mine.
5. I would also enthusiastically recommend May's "Concise Course in Algebraic Topology," but only *after* you're done with the class, and only if you enjoyed the class. It's an excellent distillation of a three-semester introductory algebraic topology course, going beyond Hatcher into areas like $K$-theory and cobordism. Reading it feels like the author is telling you what was secretly going on the whole time behind the scenes while you were in introductory class, and it makes the subject more motivated and coherent and interesting. It's a hard book, though; the author himself even warns against using it as a first textbook in his own introduction. Reading it for a first course would be like trying to pick up algebraic geometry from the Stacks project.

As for homological algebra, Atiyah-MacDonald is the canonical reference; I picked up a copy back when I started studying algebraic geometry, and it's probably still the general go-to reference. Eisenbud's "Commutative Algebraic with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry" is undoubtedly overkill for something like this, but you just pick specific chapters or appendices to get what you want. I actually like Reid's "Undergraduate Commutative Algebra" quite a bit; it's a short, clearly written text that goes through the most useful bits of commutative algebra at this level (modules, exact sequences, localization, etc.) and hits some more technical results at this level without being bogged down by them. It's a nice little book, and I'm not sure why it isn't more popular.

As for categories, you're probably fine just skimming the first chapter or two of MacLane's "Categories for the Working Mathematician." At this level, categories are really used just for bookkeeping rather than anything in themselves; it's like the difference between the general naive set theory you'd see in, say, an intro group theory class versus what set theorists themselves do. You're probably going to stay in the category of commutative modules over something like $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q},$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ throughout. There are certainly useful things from category theory that pop in algebraic topology, such as Yoneda's lemma, but you're unlikely to see them in a first course.